# Multiple dates are not working with epoch comparison in bash

Tags: bash, shell

```
printf "%s\n" "$EXPDATES"

Jul 12 2019 12:00:00
Jul 12 2019 12:00:00
Jul 12 2019 12:00:00
Jun 18 2019 12:00:00

Aug 8 2019 12:00:00
May 8 2018 00:00:00
```

The above o/p I'm getting from "for loop" and passing all the dates (including one empty line) in same format to another "for loop" to convert and compare with current "epoch".

```
curr_epoch=$(date +%s)

for expdate in "${EXPDATES[@]}"; do
  exp_epoch=$(date +%s -d "$expdate")
  if (( curr_epoch > exp_epoch )); then
    echo "$expdate in future."
  else
    echo "$expdate in past."
  fi
done
```

Here I'm not getting proper output for all the dates. "$expdate" in echo line doesn't return anything.

I'm not sure whether for-loop is comparing all the dates.

Can anyone please tell me how to compare all the dates and show output with all the dates compared?

Comment: Strictly NO BOLD font letters please in your post, kindly edit your post now.

Comment: Please show how you define the `EXPDATES` variable. I'm not convinced that it's an array.

Comment: What does o/p mean?

Comment: @PierreFrançois Output :)

Comment: `declare -p EXPDATES`, by the way, will dump a current definition of that variable (which, if incorporated into the code, would make it closer to a self-contained [mcve]). Note that in general, a code snippet in a question is expected to have already been tested to create the question at hand.

Comment: To extend what @glennjackman was saying -- I'm quite certain that `EXPDATES` **is not** an array. If `printf '%s\n' "$EXPDATES"` prints more than *the very first date only*, then `EXPDATES` has all those dates in the first array element (if it's in fact an array at all), rather than having one date per element.

Comment: @PierreFrançois o/p = Output

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ending quotes for the echo lines in your code. This will work:

```
for expdate in "${EXPDATES[@]}"; do
  exp_epoch=$(date +%s -d "$expdate")
  if (( curr_epoch > exp_epoch )); then
    echo "$expdate in future."
  else
    echo "$expdate in past."
  fi
done
```

Comment: If `printf "%s\n" "$EXPDATES"` prints that whole list of dates (as the OP shows in their question), then `"${EXPDATES[@]}"` will emit a multi-line string with the complete list in the first round of the `for` loop. Consequently, this code isn't appropriate for the data as the OP has it actually formed.

Comment: As I didn't have the array available, I simply used a while-loop on the contents of a file for debugging purposes. This gave me the output line by line into $expdate. I focused on the part that wasn't working at all: The echo-lines. :)

Comment: That was almost certainly a data-entry error in asking a question -- were it otherwise, the OP would have a different problem: Not the `echo`s substituting an empty string for `$expdate`, but a syntax error, or content they expected to be syntax being emitted as part of their string.

Comment: The script runs without any issues in the original version. It just doesn't show any output. Multi-line echos are valid in bash. ;)

Comment: This is, by the way, part of why [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) advises you **not to try to answer** questions that are ambiguous. If the OP had provided a true [mcve] with an exact error message and code that produced that error when someone else ran it, there'd be no room for guessing and argument.

Comment: I agree - so the result would be to downvote the question or request further instructions via comments?

Comment: Right -- and/or to vote-to-close (see what's presently the 3rd entry in the "off-topic" submenu). Since the necessary clarification was requested by Glenn ~40 minutes ago, further comments are probably unnecessary at the moment.